# Change output directory in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

I'm using setup from setuptools to create a `setup.py`, and I was wondering if it's possible to change the output directory programmatically to change it from `dist/`.

I'm aware that you can do this from the command line using the `--dist-dir` flag, but I want to be able to do from *within* the `setup.py` file instead.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override code that [set the default name](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/537b6caa565ec2fc304ba6f4400cd347ce2af64b/Lib/distutils/command/bdist.py#L115):

```
from distutils.command.bdist import bdist as _bdist
from distutils.command.sdist import sdist as _sdist

dist_dir = 'my-dist-dir'

class bdist(_bdist):
    def finalize_options(self):
        _bdist.finalize_options(self)
        self.dist_dir = dist_dir

class sdist(_sdist):
    def finalize_options(self):
        _sdist.finalize_options(self)
        self.dist_dir = dist_dir

setup(
    cmdclass={
        'bdist': bdist,
        'sdist': sdist,
    },
    …
)
```

Other `bdist_*` commands [copy the value from `bdist`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/537b6caa565ec2fc304ba6f4400cd347ce2af64b/Lib/distutils/command/bdist_dumb.py#L74).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. So it looks like it isn't one of the kw args for `setup` then? I that overriding the sdist is a bit overkill.

Comment: You can pass `dist_dir` to `setup()` but you need to do that conditionally: don't do that for non `bdist_*` commands.