# How do I run tests as part of setup.py install?

Tags: python, pip, pytest, setup.py

Currently my setup.py is set up such that

```
python setup.py test
```

will run my tests. But I'd like "python setup.py test" to be done at the end of any of the following as well:

```
python setup.py develop
python setup.py install
python setup.py build_ext -i
```

including after an installation from PyPI/pip.

What changes can I make to setup.py to do this?

Comment: This is a Python distutils project.

Comment: You need to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54632052/7976758. Override `develop`, `install` and `build_ext` classes and in their [`run`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44850698/7976758) method call parent's `run` and then call `self.run_command('test')`.

Comment: If i override with 
class CustomInstall(install):                                                                           
    def run(self):                                                                                      
        install.run(self)
this results in an infinite loop when installing.

Comment: Can you show a simplified `setup.py` that fails with an infinite loop?

Comment: The answer to this question that I've settled on after about a day of research is: "you don't - use tox instead".